Truncated distribution and the property of its expected value
I have a complicated random variable $Y$ where the support is on $\mathbb{R}$ (real value). Now, we construct a truncated random variable $\tilde{Y}$ such that
$\tilde{Y}=Y$ if $-C_0\leq Y\leq C_1$, $\tilde{Y}=C_1$ if $Y\ge C_1$, and $\tilde{Y}=-C_0$ if $Y\le -C_0$, where $C_1$ and $C_0$ are positive real number. We firstly consider the case $E_{Y}[\tilde{Y}]>0$ and $E_Y[Y]>0$.
My question is what is the ratio $\frac{E_{Y}[Y]}{E_{Y}[\tilde{Y}]}$? Is there any theorem talking about this?

I think in general you have to compute the expectation explicitly. But there are definitely some special cases, e.g., if the distribution of Y is symmetric at the axis $\frac{C_1 - C_0}{2}$, then the ratio should be 1; Also, if the tails to the right of $C_1$ and to the left of $-C_0$ are small, then the ratio should be lower-bounded too.

@VezenBU Thank you for your reply. I can decompose the denominator as $$E_Y[\tilde{Y}]=P(Y\geq C_1) C_1 - P(Y\leq -C_0)C_0 + P(-C_0<Y<C_1)E_Y[Y|-C_0<Y<C_1]$$  I think we have to analyze whether $E_Y[Y|-C_0<Y<C_1]>E_Y[Y]$ or $E_Y[Y|-C_0<Y<C_1]\leq E_Y[Y]$?
